# How to implement multiple chat rooms with AWS API Gateway websockets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, websocket, aws-api-gateway

https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/announcing-websocket-apis-in-amazon-api-gateway/

I understood how this can be accomplished with a single chat 'room'. All of the messages would go through the 'sendMessage' route key in the API Gateway.

How would this be done if I had multiple chat 'rooms' with different sets of users?

Answer (score 5):

[This web page](http://penguinitis.g1.xrea.com/computer/programming/AWS/API_Gateway_WebSocket.html) instructs how to implement multiple chat rooms with AWS API gateway storing room id with connection id in DynamoDB.
Apologize that this is written in Japanese but I guess the code itself can explain enough.

Comment: chrome translated site to English and it's really helpful, got everything needed to see a way to make it happen on aws, thanks for sharing 